# Remote C debugging with Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, remote-debugging

I am new to eclipse and running eclipse on fedora. I have to debug an embedded application using fedora. The embedded system runs linux. I am able to debug through command line by running gdbserver on the board. I want to know the eclipse settings for the remote debugging.  Can you help me please?

Thanks in advance.